# Connecting Flask with MySQL and MongoDB simultaneously

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, mongoengine

I have a Flask Backend and I'm trying to connect MySQL to MongoDb at the same time. However, I'm constantly experiecing this error.
I'm using sqlalchemy as well that's instantiated in the db file. Requests to MySQL server is fine but get request to mongodb returns me the following error:

MongoDB is currently hosted on EC2 while my flask app is local.

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError:`

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from db import db
from books.resource import Review, ReviewList

from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
import setting.mongo_setup as mongo_setup

app = Flask(__name__)
# mongo_setup.global_init()

# app.config.from_pyfile('setting/mongo_setting.py')
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
    'db': 'meta',
    'host': 'XXXXXXXX',
    'port': XXX
}
app.config.from_pyfile('setting/sql_setting.py')

mongo_db = MongoEngine()
mongo_db.init_app(app)
db.init_app(app)

api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(Review, '/review/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

**sql_setting.py:**

````
import os

MYSQL_HOST = 'XXXXXXX'
MYSQL_PORT = XXXXX
DBNAME = "XXXXX"
MYSQL_USERNAME = "XXXXXX"
MYSQL_PASSWORD = "XXXXXX"

MYSQL_URI = "mysql+pymysql://%s:%s@%s:3306/%s" % (MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_HOST, DBNAME)
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = MYSQL_URI```
````

Comment: are you sure the ec2 instance is exposed to public ? you should try connecting to the mongodb instance via the mongo cli tool once

Answer (score 0):

a)

```py
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
#__snip__
    'connect': 'direct',
}
```

might do the trick

b) you should omit the mongo IP addr from the code and error image.

Comment: Which MONGO_URI you're referring to?

Comment: I'm getting this error now instead:
```File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 320, in _create_connection
    raise ConnectionFailure("Cannot connect to database {} :\n{}".format(alias, e))
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionFailure: Cannot connect to database default :
Unknown option connection```

Comment: Please update your question with information about the infra. what version of mongoengine are you using ? Are you using docker ? is the mongo instance on a different machine/server than the flask backend ? or is it another docker container on same host ? is it AWS ec2 with vpc configured ? or is it GCP ? and more

Answer (score 0):

can you telnet to the mongo host

```
telnet x.x.x.x 27017
```

(where `x.x.x.x` is the mongo ip addr)

The error in the image usually occurs when there is a connectivity issue/ ports/connections are not whitelisted/allowed in the firewall or Security group

Comment: Hi Omkar! What am I supposed to see from performing telnet?

Comment: by performing telnet, you should be able to see whether the mongo instance is reachable or not from your server